# Zero divisor in an extension but not in a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is probably a silly question, but I can't find an answer:

> Assume that $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$, and $S$ is a subring of $R$ (in particular $1 \in S$). Assume that $x \in S \neq \{0\}$ in a zero divisor in $R$, i.e. $\exists r \in R , r \neq 0, rx=0$. Does it follow that $x$ is a zero divisor in $S$?

I think that this is wrong. $R$ can't be an integral domain. So I tried some non-integral domains, but the finite ones are not interesting, since they don't have any non-trivial subrings. I tried $R=\Bbb Q \times \Bbb R$ but it didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: What didn't work in that example?

Comment: If I try the subring $S=\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$, then I don't see what $x \in S$ I should take… I only see $x=(a,0)$ or $x=(0,b)$ as zero divisors in $R$ (and elements of $S$) but these are zero divisors in $S$.

Comment: Maybe you need to change the subring you are considering

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez : Maybe, but if I take a subring $S \subset R=\Bbb Q \times \Bbb R$, then the zero divisors in $R$ are of the form $x=(a,0)$ or $x=(0,b)$ (aren't they?) and then a zero divisor in $R$ that belongs to $S$ will be a zero divisor in $S$ (just take $s=(0,1)$ or $s=(1,0) \in S$, so that $sx=0$).

Comment: Ah we don't know $(0,1) \in S$ actually… Maybe I could try $$S=\{(x,x) \mid x \in \Bbb Z\}$$

Comment: And now things work?

Comment: I will check again but I think so!

Comment: Good ;-) ${}{}$

Comment: No, your last attempt still does not work :  a non-zero element in  $S$ is a zero-divisor neither in $S$ nor in $R$.

Comment: Also, your penultimate sentence is false: $\mathbb Z/2\subset  \frac {(\mathbb Z/2)[X]}{(X^2)}$

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : I agree that my last attempt doesn't work. Do you see any suitable subring $S \subset \Bbb Q \times \Bbb R$ (and an element $x \in S$) that would work? I don't see…

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : ok, understood. Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: You are welcome, dear Alphonse.

Comment: Assume that there is a subring $S$ of $R:=\Bbb Q \times \Bbb R$ and an element $(a,b) \in S\setminus \{(0,0)\} $ which is a zero divisor in $R$ but not in $S$. 

In other words:
$$\exists (x,y) \in R \setminus \{(0,0)\} \quad (ax,by)=(0,0)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\forall (x',y') \in S \setminus \{(0,0)\} \quad (ax',by') \neq (0,0)$$

Comment: My try: if $(ax,by)=(0,0)$ then $a=0$ or $x=0$, and $b=0$ or $y=0$. Assume that $a \neq 0$ without loss of generality. Then $x=0$, but we can't have also $y=0$, so that $b=0$, i.e. $$(a,b)=(a,0) ; (x,y)=(0,y).$$

I want that for any $(x',y') \in S$, $$ax'=0=by' \implies x'=0=y'$$
I must have $(1,1),(a,0) \in S.$
Then $(x',y'):=(0,a) \in S$. Since $ax'=0=0 \cdot y'$, it follows that $x'=0=y'=a$, contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the inclusion  $$S=\mathbb Z[x]\hookrightarrow R=\mathbb Z[x,y]=\frac {\mathbb Z[X,Y]}{(X\cdot Y)}$$ The element  $x\in S$ is not a zero divisor in $S$ but $x$ is a zero divisor in $R$ since $y\neq 0$ and  $xy=0$.